# Flask-Restful Object not serializable errors on return code 200

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, flask, flask-restful, flask-cors

Im currently getting a strange error whenever I try to return a response with the code 200.

Here's the snippet of the code I'm using:

```
from pathlib import Path
from flask_restful import Resource
from app.models.user import User
from app.models.workspace import Workspace
from app.models.file import File
from app.controllers.filesystem import FileSystem
from flask import request
import os

class Signup(Resource):
   def post(self):

    if not request.is_json:
        return {"msg": "Missing JSON in request"}, 400

    email = request.json.get('email', None)
    password = request.json.get('password', None)
    if not email:
        return {"msg": "Missing username parameter"}, 400
    if not password:
        return {"msg": "Missing password parameter"}, 400

    # TODO- Find a more elegant way to do this
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        user = None

    if user:
        return {"msg": "User already exists"}, 400

    new_user = User(email=email, password=password)
    new_user.hash_password()
    
    # Create a new workspace called "Microfluidics Examples"
    new_workspace = Workspace(name="Microfluidics Examples")
    
    # Step 1 - Go through every file in the examples directory 
    # Step 2 - Upload these files to s3 and get the file_id
    # Step 3 - Create a new file object for each of the file_ids and add it to the workspace
    
    # Go through every file in the examples directory
    examples_directory = Path("examples")
    for file_name in examples_directory.iterdir():
        # Upload the file to s3 and get the file_id
        s3_object_id = FileSystem.upload_file(file_name)
        
        # Create a new file object for the file_id and add it to the workspace
        new_file = File(file_name=str(file_name.name), s3_path=s3_object_id)
        new_file.save()
        new_workspace.design_files.append(new_file)
    
    # Save the workspace
    new_workspace.save()
    
    # Add the workspace to the user
    new_user.workspaces.append(new_workspace)
    
    # Save the user        
    new_user.save()
    
    # Return success
    return {"mes":, "id": str(new_user.id)}, 200
```

From the error trace, it looks like something originating from the cors package might be interfering with this. Here's the trace:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Nov/2022 14:18:02] "GET /api/v2/user HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 471, in wrapper
    return self.make_response(data, code, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 500, in make_response
    resp = self.representations[mediatype](data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask_restful/representations/json.py", line 21, in output_json
    dumped = dumps(data, **settings) + "\n"
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable
```

I can't figure out why this is happening; for instance, if I change the return code to 400, it just works fine. Can someone help me figure out what this error is?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies to the community, I traced the error incorrectly. The error did not originate because of the given code snippet. I will update the question shortly to reflect the source of the error trace correctly and post the solution